# What is the difference between ActionContext.RequestContext and HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, ioc-container

I am using the standard OAuth implementation into a WebApi utilizing a custom authorization attribute to verify the user.

Nearly exactly like Method 2 detailed [here](http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/)

My question is any information adding into the claim like so:

```
            IList<Claim> claimsCollection = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, authUser.UserName),
                new Claim("userID", authUser.UserID.ToString()),
                new Claim("dbServer", dbServer),
                new Claim("dbName", dbName)
            };

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaims(claimsCollection);

        //add in any permission specific claimns
        if (securityClaimCollection.Count > 0) { oAuthIdentity.AddClaims(securityClaimCollection); };

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);
        context.Validated(ticket);
```

Only exists in the Controller's ActionContext.RequestContext.Principal. Why? Is there no way of retrieving data in the claims other than from the controller? Essentially I am asking so that information placed in the claim can be accessed by an IoC container and used for injection into a IDBConnection type.